# Multiple Array puzzle

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have an array :

```
$myArrays = array(
    array(1, 2, 3, 4),
    array(5, 6, 7, 8),
    array(9, 10, 11, 12),
    array(13, 14, 15, 16)
);
```

i need to print output:

```
1
5
9
13
14
10
6
2
3
7
11
15
16
12
8
4
```

Comment: show us what you have done so far!

Comment: are arrays inside the array all of the same length?

Comment: yes  arrays inside the array all of the same length 4*4

Comment: Try shuffle() method

Comment: Any simple program to achive this  logic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using combination of [array_map](http://php.net/array_map), [array_column](http://php.net/array_column) and [array_reverse](http://php.net/array_reverse) :

```
$myArrays = array(
    array(1, 2, 3, 4),
    array(5, 6, 7, 8),
    array(9, 10, 11, 12),
    array(13, 14, 15, 16)
);

$index = 0;
$myArrays = array_map(function ($v) use (&$index, $myArrays) {
    if (($index % 2) != 0) {
        echo implode("\n", array_reverse(array_column($myArrays, $index))) . "\n";
    } else {
        echo implode("\n", array_column($myArrays, $index)) . "\n";
    }

    $index++;
}, $myArrays);
```

live demo : https://3v4l.org/0m2jZ

---

using foreach instead of array_map

```
foreach ($myArrays as $index => $myArray) {
    if (($index % 2) != 0) {
        echo implode("\n", array_reverse(array_column($myArrays, $index))) . "\n";
    } else {
        echo implode("\n", array_column($myArrays, $index)) . "\n";
    }
}
```

live demo : https://3v4l.org/RNC9R

---

both will output the following :

```
1
5
9
13
14
10
6
2
3
7
11
15
16
12
8
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have really badly written code, but works for your problem. Array dimensions have to be 4*4.

```
<?php
$myArrays = array(
    array(1, 2, 3, 4),
    array(5, 6, 7, 8),
    array(9, 10, 11, 12),
    array(13, 14, 15, 16)
);

$counter1 = 0;

while($counter1 < 4)
{
    echo $myArrays[$counter1][0];
    echo "\n";
    $counter1++;
    }

    $counter1 = 3;

    while($counter1 >= 0)
    {
        echo $myArrays[$counter1][1];
        echo "\n";
        $counter1--;        
    }

    $counter1 = 0;

    while($counter1 < 4)
    {
        echo $myArrays[$counter1][2];
        echo "\n";
        $counter1++;
    }

    $counter1 = 3;

    while($counter1 >= 0)
    {
        echo $myArrays[$counter1][3];
        echo "\n";
        $counter1--;
    }
    ?>
```